# F#: Is there a way to extend the monad keyword list?

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression, dynamic-keyword

Inside an F# monad, if you say `let!`, the compiler translates that to a `Bind` member that you've defined on the monad builder.

Now I see there are Query monads, as [shown here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where you can say:

```
query {
    for student in db.Student do
    select student
    count
}
```

and the `select` and `count`, for example, will be translated to the [`QueryBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323943%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) members [Linq.QueryBuilder.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/querybuilder.select%5B%27t%2C%27q%2C%27result%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) and [`Linq.QueryBuilder.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/querybuilder.count%5B%27t%2C%27q%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D).

My question is, is this mapping of keywords to members hardwired into the F# compiler, or is it extensible? For example, can I say something like:

```
FooMonadBuilder() {
    bar
}
```

and somehow tell the F# compiler that `bar` maps to a `FooMonadBuilder.Bar()` method?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In F# 2.0 (that is Visual Studio 2010), there is no way to extend the keyword list (other than Ramon's extension). However, the query mechanism in F# 3.0 (Visual Sutdio 11) is extensible and you can define your own keywords similar to `select` and `count`.

Here is a basic example that defines something like `seq` builder with `reverse` keyword:

```
type SeqBuilder() =
    // Standard definition for 'for' and 'yield' in sequences
    member x.For (source : seq<'T>, body : 'T -> seq<'R>) =
      seq { for v in source do yield! body v }
    member x.Yield item =
      seq { yield item }

    // Define an operation 'select' that performs projection
    [<CustomOperation("select")>]
    member x.Select (source : seq<'T>, [<ProjectionParameter>] f: 'T -> 'R) : seq<'R> =
        Seq.map f source

    // Defines an operation 'reverse' that reverses the sequence    
    [<CustomOperation("reverse", MaintainsVariableSpace = true)>]
    member x.Expand (source : seq<'T>) =
        List.ofSeq source |> List.rev

let mseq = SeqBuilder()
```

The details how this works are not yet documented, but the `CustomOperation` attribute says that the operation should be treated as a special syntax (you can set various properties to specify how it behaves - `MaintainsVariableSpace` means that it does not change the values inside sequence). The `Projectionparameter` attribute specifies that the expression following the keyword should be implicitly converted to a function.

Now, the `mseq` builder supports both `select` and `reverse`:

```
let q = mseq { for i in 1 .. 10 do
               select (i + 100)
               reverse }
```

Comment: Could you define joinads with these extensions? I don't imagine you can; just curious.

Comment: Fantastic. Looking forward to reading all about that. Also looking forward to playing around with that CustomOperation attribute in a non-query-related monad and seeing what happens. :)

Comment: The first thing I'm going to do with this is make an AI DSL for a new video game prototype.

Comment: @gradbot That sounds cool :-) I'd love to see that. I imagine it would be nice for encoding Solver Foundation problems too.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Is MaintainsVariableSpace attribute really required since by default 'source' is immutable? Also I tried your code without the attribute and the result is the same with or w/o the attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no.

I've extended the compiler to support that, you're welcome to read my blog article http://ramon.org.il/wp/2011/04/taking-computation-expressions-one-step-further/

Comment: Thank you Ramon. If it's not available in the language I doubt I'll end up doing it, but I'm looking forward to reading how you did it.