# Defining new keywords in F#'s computation expression

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression, f#-3.0

The F# 3.0 beta contains a [query {}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) computation expression with tons of new keywords.

How can I define my own keywords in a computation builder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In F# 3.0, you can use [CustomOperationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289709%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose.

The new attribute is not very well-documented, the only examples I find are this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272285/f-is-there-a-way-to-extend-the-monad-keyword-list/9275289#9275289) by @Tomas and this [interesting blog post](http://mnajder.blogspot.com/2011/09/when-reactive-framework-meets-f-30.html).

Answer (score 0):

F# computation expressions support custom keywords. This lets you define custom commands inside computation expression. Saturn - the web framework in F# uses this extensively.

```
type FooBuilder() =
    member t.Yield _ = String.Empty

    [<CustomOperation("fooCommand")>]
    member _.myFooCommand(state, arg1:string, arg2:string) =
        // do something with arg1 and arg2
        0

    [<CustomOperation("fooRun")>]
    member _.myFooRunMethod(state, arg1: float) =
        // do something with arg1 
        0
            

let foo = FooBuilder()
let _ = foo {
        fooCommand "dotnet" "--help"
        fooRun 3.14
}
```

You can thread a 'state' through the calls. Read more about it in the article by Isaac Abraham on this topic -- https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/custom-keywords-in-computation-expressions/

Saturn code -- https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn