# Extending Query Expressions

Tags: f#

Are there any documents or examples out there on how one can extend/add new keywords to query expressions?  Is this even possible?

For example, I'd like to add a lead/lag operator.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565986/defining-new-keywords-in-fs-computation-expression). The last link in my answer may be of your interest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to the [query builder for the Rx Framework](http://mnajder.blogspot.cz/2011/09/when-reactive-framework-meets-f-30.html) mentioned by @pad, there is also a talk by Wonseok Chae from the F# team about Computation Expressions that includes query expressions. I'm not sure if the meeting was recorded, but there are [very detailed slides](http://files.meetup.com/2922732/Computation%20Expressions%20%28April%29.pdf) with a cool example on query syntax for generating .NET IL code.

The [source code of the standard F# query builder](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/Query.fsi) is probably the best resource for finding out what types of operations are supported and how to annotate them with attributes.

The key attributes that you'll probably need are demonstrated by the `where` clause:

```
[<CustomOperation("where",MaintainsVariableSpace=true,AllowIntoPattern=true)>]
member Where : 
  : source:QuerySource<'T,'Q> * 
    [<ProjectionParameter>] predicate:('T -> bool) -> QuerySource<'T,'Q>
```

The `CustomOperation` attribute defines the name of the operation. The (quite important) parameter `MaintainsVariableSpace` allows you to say that the operation returns the same type of values as it takes as the input. In that case, the variables defined earlier are still available after the operation. For example:

```
query { for p in db.Products do
        let name = p.ProductName
        where (p.UnitPrice.Value > 100.0M)
        select name }
```

Here, the variables `p` and `name` are still accessible after `where` because `where` only filters the input, but it does not transform the values in the list.

Finally, the `ProjectionParameter` allows you to say that `p.UnitValue > 100.0M` should actually be turned into a function that takes the context (available variables) and evaluates this expression. If you do not specify this attribute, then the operation just gets the value of the argument as in:

```
query { for p in .. do
        take 10 }
```

Here, the argument `10` is just a simple expression that cannot use values in `p`.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that these can be extension methods on the standard query builder type.

Comment: Very cool!  Thanks for the links.  Interesting that one can use existing linq extensions to accomplish what they want here as well.

Comment: @kvb That is very cool! But then you also need to add that they won't work with the standard providers for LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities :-( (unless you write some pre-processor that transforms them to something else that is supported in the expression tree?)

Comment: Right, they'll only work with IEnumerables, not IQueryables.  This can be enforced by making sure that the input and output types are more specific (see my comment on davewolfs's other answer).

Answer (score 6):

Pretty cool feature for the language.  Just implemented the reverse to query QuerySource.

Simple example, but just a demonstration.

```
module QueryExtensions

type ExtendedQueryBuilder() =
    inherit Linq.QueryBuilder()
    /// Defines an operation 'reverse' that reverses the sequence    
    [<CustomOperation("reverse", MaintainsVariableSpace = true)>]
    member __.Reverse (source : Linq.QuerySource<'T,System.Collections.IEnumerable>) =
        let reversed = source.Source |> List.ofSeq |> List.rev
        new Linq.QuerySource<'T,System.Collections.IEnumerable>(reversed)


let query = ExtendedQueryBuilder()
```

And now it being used.

```
let a = [1 .. 100]

let specialReverse = 
    query {
        for i in a do
        select i
        reverse
    }
```

Comment: Note that you may want to use `System.Collections.IEnumerable` in both places where you've got `'Q`, since the standard IQueryable providers don't know how to handle your operation and will throw a runtime exception if it's used.

Comment: It seems to run fine, but will add.  Can you explain that in more detail?  What do they know how to handle?

Comment: Basically, IQueryable providers work against a quoted version of the query, and only recognize the built-in operators.  So if you did something like `query { for x in myDatabaseTable do reverse }` where `myDatabaseTable` is a LINQ table, then the query would fail at runtime.

Comment: If you restrict the `'Q` type parameter to `IEnumerable`, then the query will succeed at runtime, but run all of the logic on the client side (rather than trying to generate a server-side query).